# Can't login using AuthComponent in Cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I guess this is a silly question but I'm having trouble logging in to the restricted sections of a site I'm building in Cake.

For starting I see that the password string in `$this->request->data['Usuario']['clave']` is not the same as the hashed string using `SimplePasswordHasher` in the `beforeSave` function at the model. I should also say that the model is not the default Users model, because I'm writing the application for spanish language and I didn't want to use the default model, so my configuration of the component is:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    /*function beforeFilter() {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    }*/
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'Form'=>array(
                'userModel' => 'Usuario',
                'unauthorizedRedirect' => false,
                'loginRedirect' => array(
                    'controller' => 'ComplejosResidenciales',
                    'action' => 'index'
                ),
                'logOutRedirect' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Usuarios',
                    'action' => 'index'
                ),
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'usuario',
                    'password' => 'clave'
                ),
                'authorize' => 'Controller'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

So I decided not to hash the password field, but still to no avail. 
I wish anyone could lend me a hand on this because I'm newbie to CakePHP and don't know how to fix it.

I figure it must be something with the `Auth->login()` method because I'm not following conventions here, but I don't know how to configure the said method. Currently is like follows:

```
public function login() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->Auth->redirectUrl($this->Auth->redirectUrl());    
        }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Las credenciales proporcionadas no son correctas'), 'default', array(), 'auth');   
        }
```

As rrd pointed, my $components array was wrong, so I changed it to:

```
public $components = array(
'Session',
'Auth'=>array('loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'ComplejosResidenciales',     'action'=>'index'), 'logOutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'Usuarios', 'action'=>'index'),     'loginAction'=>array('controller'=>'Usuarios', 'action'=>'login'),     'authenticate'=>array('Form'=>array('userModel'=>'Usuario',     'fields'=>array('username'=>'usuario', 'password'=>'clave')))));
```

Which is better, according to cakephp.org

> Do not put other Auth configuration keys (like authError, loginAction etc) within the authenticate or Form element. They should be at the same level as the authenticate key.

But it isn't working.

Been struggling with it and I can't get the hang of it, I wish someone would point out what I'm doing wrong. In my AppController I have declared the component and the beforeFilter function like this:

```
public $components =     array('Auth'=>array('loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'ComplejosResidenciales',     'action'=>'index'), 
'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'Usuarios', 'action'=>'login'), 
), 'Session');

public function beforeFilter(){
      $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
         AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'Usuario', "fields" =>   array("username" => "usuario", "password" => "clave"), 'Form'));
}
```

And then I have the login function which goes (obviously I guess) in the UsuariosController, like this:

```
public function login() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
    if($this->Auth->login()) {
    return $this->Auth->redirectUrl($this->Auth->loginRedirect);    
    }
    else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Las credenciales proporcionadas no son correctas'),     'default', array(), 'auth');   
    }
    }
    }
```

But I just keep seeing the message "Las credenciales proporcionadas no son correctas". I don't know if I'm calling the method of Auth component correctly in the part `$this->Auth->login()` because apparently I have no result when calling it like that, without arguments, but I tried calling it with the argument `$this->request->data` and as a result it didn't mattered what I wrote in the username and password fields, anything would pass, which is bad, of course.

Now I see why coding `$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)` resulted in giving unrestricted access:

> In 2.x $this->Auth->login($this->request->data) will log the user in with whatever data is posted, whereas in 1.3 $this->Auth->login($this->data) would try to identify the user first and only log in when successful.

According to cake's manual. I can't seem to read correctly any document about this. Anyway, I beg someone would help me because I'm in a hurry here. After reading some other documents I guess that Auth component should handle everything correctly, as long as I provide the right configuration, so I've ended up doing a `beforeFilter()` call in the AppController, like this:

```
var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');

public function beforeFilter() {
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'Usuarios', 'action'=>'login');
$this->Auth->redirectLogin = array('controller'=>'ComplejosResidenciales',   'action'=>'add');
$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form'=>array('userModel'=>'Usuario',     'fields'=>array('username'=>'usuario', 'password'=>'clave')));
}
```

Then, in my "UsuariosController" I do:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view', 'add', 'edit', 'delete');   
    }
```

And I have my login and logout functions, very simple, but it's not working, and it does not redirect me upon logging in nor does it let me access any other controller, it seems to do nothing. Please help!

```
/**
* login and logout functions
* 
*/

    public function login() {
    }
    public function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
```

Comment: Well for this you should be clear about the main principles of Auth. Read the manual or a book like https://leanpub.com/CakePHPUserAuthentication

Your Auth array declaration is not right. What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: @rrd I'm using cake 2.4.5, but I don't get what is wrong with my declaration of the component, I really haven't developed much the authorization part, but for now I'm just trying to restrict all the controllers and allow them as needed in the beforeFilter part of each

Answer (score 0):

You should change more things.

$components should be something like this:

```
public $components = array(
            'Session',
            'Auth' => array(
                'authenticate' => array(
                    'Form' => array(
                        'fields' => array('username'=>'usuario', 'password'=>'clave')
                    )
                )
            )
    );
```

I am not sure about userModel, check the manual.

Than you should implement isAuthorized

```
function isAuthorized($user){
if(in_array($this->action, array('view', 'edit')))
    return true;
return false;
}
```

beforeFilter is not necessary for your case.

Your login method is something like this.

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
            }
        }
    }
```

Again, I recommend you to read the manual or the book mentioned above. It has a free sample, I think You will get the main idea by that.